# a question for ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question and the description are listed below. There is an idea that the number can be taken from the complex number field, but I can't make it. Can anybody help me with it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oooR7.png)

Show that in addition to the special solution Y = C3 to the differential equation in (1.1.9) there is another special solution of the form Y = -2/(C4 + In x) - 1, where C4 is arbitrary. The derivation of the general solution to (1.1.9) is given in Example 2 of Sec. 1.7. Explain how this special solution can arise in the derivation of the general solution. Also show how this special solution can be interpreted as a singular limit of the general solution in (1.1.10). Please help me with step by step to understand this is the exact problem from the textbook.

$$\rm{(1.1.9).} \;\;y''=\dfrac yxy'$$

Answer (score 2):

$$y''=\dfrac {yy'}x$$
$$xy''=yy'$$
$$xy''\color {red}{+y'}=\dfrac 12 (y^2)'\color{red}{+y'}$$
Integrate;
$$xy'=\dfrac 12 y^2+y+C$$
This DE is separable.